# How can I get json reponse in Spring Boot 2.7.0?

Tags: json, xml, spring-boot

It used to send JSON response in spring boot 2.2.6.RELEASE.
I upgraded spring boot version to 2.7.0 and now it sends xml response.
I want to receive json response.

This is my pom.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    ...

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.12</org.projectlombok.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        ...
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        ...

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        
    </dependencyManagement>

    ...
</project>
```

And this is postman result.
In postman, I see content-type=application/xml;charset=utf8.
I did not specify content-type anywhere in the code. And in spring boot 2.2.6.RELEASE, it was automatically json. I don't know where to explicitly specify it.
[image]
I can't find any solution. Is there anyone with similar experience?

Comment: maybe you have to define produce type in definition of `@PostMapping(produces = { "application/json" })`

Answer (score 0):

You can force the response type at your `@PostMapping` by adding the producer, like below :

```
> @PostMapping(value = "/login",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```